# AttributeProviderAttribute work, and attribute redirection mechanics in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

Hello all and everyone! 
English is not my native language. I apologize for any errors.

I decided to use the AttributeProviderAttribute to reduce repetitions in the code. But I don’t understand how to check: does attribute redirection work or not? And how are contradictions between their own attributes and redirected attributes handled?

```
//using namespaces
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

//Test Classes Foo, Bar:

public class Foo {
    [DisplayName(nameof(Astring) + "Name")]
    public string Astring { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [AttributeProvider(nameof(Foo), nameof(Foo.Astring))]
    public string Bstring { get; set; }
}

// Code for checking attributes:
PropertyInfo bStrProp = typeof(Bar).GetProperty(nameof(Bar.Bstring));
```

Questions:

1. The debugger does not display a DisplayNameAttribute for `Bar.Bstring`. How do I know if attribute redirection worked?
2. How are contradictions between own attributes and redirected from another property handled?

   a. Priority own attributes.

   b. Priority imported attributes.

   c. Priority last attributes.

   d. An exception is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Meta data analyzing code must explicitly support AttributeProviderAttribute to be usefully assigned to a property.